# node.js InApp and schedule

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am doing a mobile game server using node.js. I used the `Express` and `postgresql`
I have two questions.

1. This game has a Inapp is `30 daily gems` that user can get the gems in 30 days period. But I don't know how to implement the method let the server know the user bought this item and send the reward to this user every day.
2. This game has a special offer item in InApp. For example, a Christmas pack in 25/12 - 27/12. But I don't know how to set this 3 days can show this pack.

I am beginner in node.js. So I hope that you don't think my question is stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Speaking at a high level, you have quite a few options.

1. For your gems requirement, you would probably have a field or table that represents this gem purchase, e.g a start date. If a user bought this package say on 1/1/2019 then your node server can have a process that runs once a day that queries the purchase table and give gems to any user where the current date is less than 30 days ahead of the purchased date.

Your table may look like:

```
user_id

date_purchased

gems_per_day
```

To implement this as a function that will run once a day, you may want to create a singular script for it and run it on a cron job once per day or create a Timer type class within Node that will run your function every 24 hours.

2. For your special offers, as part of your Store code, let's say you have a function that updates what items are currently available in the store, you run this code once per day (as one of the 2 methods mentioned above) and probably storing these items in your database. Similarly, you can check each day if the current date is within this "special offer period" and if it is, you can set that product within your database to be active.

Your table may look like:

```
product_id
enabled
```

or

```
product_id
start_dayMonth
end_dayMonth
```

Hope this gives you a few ideas of how you can lay this out. Happy to answer any questions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get some concept in your answer. But I have a question for question1. If I don't use cron job to create a scheduler, I implement a logic that the user login I check he is bought the daily gem  or not. If yes, I add the gem to his account. Do you have any idea in my opinion.

Comment: That would work fine. Possibly have a db table for daily gems with the user_id and then the current date. On every login check if there is a record with the current date for that user. If there is not then you can give them the gems and then add that record to your database.